# Why do the components of fields transform trivially under translations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory

This is a follow-up from [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692710/) question. Weinberg states in Quantum Theory of Fields Vol. 1 that creation and annihilation fields must transform as
$$U_0(\Lambda, a)\psi_l^+(x)U_0^{-1}(\Lambda, a) = \sum_\bar{l}D_{l\bar l}(\Lambda^{-1})\psi_{\bar l}^+ (\Lambda x+a).\tag{5.1.6}$$

Implicit in this statement is that under a pure translation $U_0(1, a)$, we have

$$\psi_l^+ \to \psi_l^+(x+a),$$

i.e. that the different components of $\psi_l$ do not mix. It is not obvious to me why we should assume this. Is there no non-trivial way in which the fields could transform under spacetime translations?

**EDIT:**

Following the discussion with @Prahar in the comments, I see that the fields cannot mix under a translation. However, it is still not clear to me that the fields must transform trivially under spacetime translations. That is, is there anything preventing the possibility that

$$\psi_l^+ \to e^{i\theta a} \psi_l^+(x+a)?$$

Comment: Translations are an Abelian subgroup so its irreducible reps are all one-dimensional.

Comment: @Prahar ok - but say $D_{l \bar l}(a) = e^{i\theta a}\delta_{l \bar l}$ for some $\theta$. Then $u_l(x; p, \sigma, n) = e^{ipx+i\theta x}u_l(p, \sigma, n)$. So why is $\theta=0$?

Comment: Note that if $D(a) = e^{i\theta a}$ then $D(a) = D(a+\frac{2\pi}{\theta})$. However, translations do not admit any such periodicity so we must have $\theta=0$ (translations are _not_ compact!). As an aside, note that $S^1 \cong U(1)$ is also abelian but it is compact so it's allowed to have non-trivial representations such as $D(\theta) = e^{i n \theta}$ for $n\in {\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @Prahar and why can non-compact groups not admit periodic representations?

Comment: Because then those are not really representations of the non-compact group, but representations of the compact quotient. For instance since $S^1 = {\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$, obviously every representation of $S^1$ can be elevated to that of ${\mathbb R}$ but those aren't really representations of ${\mathbb R}$, are they?

Comment: I think I'm being a bit unfair. You may be correct and in all honesty, I don't think my comment really answers your excellent question. It could be that such are incompatible with Lorentz transformations.

Comment: In the complete space of γ matrices, you use $\gamma^{\mu\nu}$ for $M^{\mu\nu}$, but then the 1-index  γ that transforms suitably under *M* as a candidate for $P^\rho$  in the Poincare' algebra is $\gamma^\rho$... But these do not commute among themselves like translations, as @Prahar  reminds you they should... It looks hard to have a spinor operator  representation of translations as a function of  γ s, no?

Comment: @awsomeguy, do you assume different $\Theta_l$ in $ \psi_l^+ \rightarrow e^{i\Theta_l \, a} \psi_l^+(x+a)$? In any case, it appears only physics can settle it, mathematics is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my world that is almost a definition. Fields are defined as sections of fiber bundles. Or more informally, assume that we have a representation of the Lorentz group $S$ and a representation of the Poincare group on "x". And then  consider
\begin{equation}
S \otimes x, 
\end{equation}
which obeys the transformation rule that you wrote.
The only part that can "transform" non-trivially under the translation algebra is an "x" part, which are just coordinates on our Minkowski space.  For example, a scalar field is just a map from $M \to \mathbb{R} $. When you do a Lorentz transformation $f$ transforms as $\Lambda^*f(x) =  f'(x) =   f(\Lambda x)$.
In some sense Weinberg is decomposing this tensor product, which is a valid representation, into a sum of the Poincare group representations.

We can consider something that has the dependence you described, but it would ruin the group composition rule and would not be a representation:
\begin{equation}
U(\Lambda_1,a_1) U(\Lambda_2,a_2) = U(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2,\Lambda_1 a_2+a_1)
\end{equation}
And consequently this tensor product would have no reason to decompose in terms of representations.